# Conversion from string "SELECT * FROM DB" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, oracle, visual-studio-2012

I am new to Visual Studio and asp.net with vb, and have been trying to crack the below code to run a simple sql query in vb to be displayed in a html format.

Code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlTypes 
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Server
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client

Public Class WebForm1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private oradb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=" _
   + "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=###.###.###.###)(PORT=####))" _
   + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=#)));" _
   + "User Id=user;Password=pwrd;"

Dim conn As New OracleConnection(oradb.ToString)
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Db WHERE CLMN = 'Y'"
Dim cmd As New OracleCommand(sql, conn)
Dim dr As OracleDataReader

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles      Me.Load
    MySub()

End Sub

Sub MySub()

    conn.Open()
    cmd.CommandType() = sql
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    dr.Read()

    GridView1.DataSource = dr.Read()

    conn.Close()
    conn.Dispose()


End Sub
End Class
```

The code breaks down at, `cmd.CommandType() = sql`

Placing `.ToString` after it i.e. `cmd.CommandType() = sql.ToString`, this then causes the code to break at the `GridView1.DataSource = dr.Read()` with an invalid DataSource error.

I have been researching a fix and seem to think that I need to declare `cmd.CommandType.Text` somewhere, but cannot do that without completely corrupting the code.

Appreciate any advice, apologies if it is an obvious one. Google hasn't been my friend on this one.

Thanks

Comment: You're putting the SQL into 'CommandType'. Should this be 'Command'?

Comment: No, changing `CommandType` to `Command` is invalid, changing it to `CommandText` then gives me this error at the `GridView1.DataSource = dr.Read()` line.

Comment: Was going from memory, but should have checked first. I'd suggest finding a good walkthrough to go through before you go any further anyway, as there's a few oddities in your code (trying to assign to a function result, putting .ToString() on a string, a dr.Read() sitting on its own, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the commandType equal to your query which is incorrect. It should be Text in your case or just omit it and it'll default to text anyway.

CommandType can only be StoredProcedure, TableDirect or Text (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype.aspx

You should instead use the CommandText propery (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtext.aspx)

Comment: Still struggling to find a solution to this. I think the CommandText property is the way to go having already checked out your link from Google. I think I need to keep searching for a good walkthrough to kick start me on this. Thanks.